# how to make an exe file run from a button click in visual c++

Tags: visual-c++

I have a form and a button on it.
I want to open a processing file which is inside a folder.
I wrote the following code which is throwing an exception.
inside the button click event the following code I wrote.

```
System::Diagnostics::Process::Start("path2file.pdf");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java , It's damn easy :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start "G:\\IISC\\dyanamic models\\eco indicator 99.pdf");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,http://stackoverflow.com/users/5903092/priyal-trivedi

Comment: Please do not post bare code. Also include an explanation for what your code is doing.

Answer (score 2):

Correct it as below:

```
System::Diagnostics::Process::Start("G:\\IISC\\dyanamic models\\eco indicator 99.pdf");
```

or

```
System::Diagnostics::Process::Start(@"G:\IISC\dyanamic models\eco indicator 99.pdf");
```